# Random dataset based on id key

Tags: python, dataset, shuffle

Random shuffle rows in a dataset
contraints: only rows can't be shuffle, not values between colums

- *np.random.permutation* can't work because it doesn't keep values per columns
- *random.shuffle* results a key error

Exemple on this table :

[image]

How to get differents rows ? for exemple line 7 becomes line 2

Comment: its not really clear, have you sample to show what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a shuffled dataframe using the `DataFrame.sample(...)` method, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df = df.sample(frac=1)
```

Here `frac=1` tells the function to shuffle the rows instead of sampling some number of rows. This will results in something like:

```
   A         B         C
6  0.539230  0.726644  0.904020
9  0.173626  0.774850  0.914098
5  0.114591  0.344212  0.339833
4  0.159820  0.604845  0.029802
3  0.826250  0.765909  0.422308
1  0.110008  0.523306  0.288052
2  0.616792  0.932205  0.659934
8  0.707413  0.794188  0.214229
7  0.409670  0.706913  0.232815
0  0.048167  0.748322  0.014002
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !